# tsql trigger that does not roll back insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, try-catch, rollback

I have one table (so called A) in my MS SQL Server database and I created after insert trigger on it that processes the inserted data and inserts some of the columns into another table (let's say B).

So far it works pretty well, but I have a problem when the second insert (triggered) into table B is not proper (ex. inserted values are not in line with integrity constraints). In this case all transactions are rolled back, especially the first insert into table A.

I'd like to have values inserted into table A even if the second insert (into table B) was wrong and was not accomplished. I've tried several versions with TRY/CATCH block but at anytime my trigger throws an error and all transaction is rolled back. Is there any way to work around this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the data to satisfy the integrity constraints prior to `INSERT` to table `B` (ie - do `WHERE EXISTS` checks as part of the `INSERT`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are totally right, I did some IF EXISTS blocks but still there is a probability to occur an error that is unexpected and not handled. The issue is that I have table A very important which is filled with data by external servers and I do not want to loose any part of this data. Table B is under my control and I can work around cases that cannot be inserted into table B.

Comment: In ideal situation I'd like to have data inserted into table A without respect of trigger behaviour and then trigger would try to insert some data into table B and update status in table A as 'insert ok' and if there were some errors marks the record in table A as 'insert error'. Then I would be able to manually check what went wrong with cases that was not inserted into table B. Is it possible to do this with trigger?

Comment: Other than relaxing table B's constraint ? I can't think of another way. These constraints are beyond your trigger's control.